# FacebookRequest::execute() not included in facebook sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After downloading [facebook sdk for php](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/archive/5.0.0.zip) i tried to run the [following](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user). The code is:

```
    function QueryToRetrieveUserThroughID(string $id) {

        $newFacebookApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp(app-id, app-secret);
        $request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
                $newFacebookApp, 'GET', '/' . $id
        );
         $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $request->getGraphObject(); 
   }
```

Though when reaching the line `$response = $request->execute();` it produces:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute()
```

Am i doing something wrong here with the idea of how to use the API or indeed FacebookRequest::execute does not exist??

Comment: That’s code written for the PHP SDK v4, whereas the current version is v5. Start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/

Answer (score 5):

It is actually an issue on Facebook for Developers page for [Facebook SDK for PHP](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk) as described on [Issue #509](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/issues/509) wherein the sample codes on the page are actually for SDK v4, thus producing errors when used on v5.

An up-to-date documentation is hosted at https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/5.5/docs/reference.md.

Using SDK v5:

```
// PHP GRAPH SDK 5.5
function QueryToRetrieveUserThroughID(string $id) {

    $newFacebook = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => '{app-id}',
        'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    $newFacebookApp = $newFacebook->getApp();
    $response = $newFacebook->get($id, '{access-token}');
    // or $response = $newFacebook->get($id);

    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
}
```

Comment: I want to add to this, that Facebook's Graph Explorer produces v4 code as well. This answers my question.