# Get Facebook page likes using PHP sdk

Tags: php, facebook

Im trying to get likes count on my page

This is the code im using but the access token is NULL

```
 $fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
   'app_id'  => 'my_app_id',
   'app_secret' => 'my_app_secret',
   'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10'
 ));

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$access_token = $helper->getAccessToken();

var_dump($access_token);
```

Im guessing that i need to grant access to the app on my page but im not sure how..

**UPDATE:**

well i have done the following

```
$fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp('app_id', 'app_secret');
$access_token = $fbApp->getAccessToken();
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest( $fbApp, $access_token , 'GET', '/fan_count');
```

How do i get the fan count from that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

It´s the `fan_count` field, the API call would be `/page-id?fields=fan_count`

What permissions/Tokens you need is explained in the docs. Usually, an App Token is good enough for getting the fan count.

API Requests with the PHP SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/

Comment: well i have done the following
$fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp('app_id', 'app_secret');
// Get access from Graph API Explorer (you should get admin access to the page first)
$access_token = $fbApp->getAccessToken();
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest( $fbApp, $access_token , 'GET', '/fan_count');

How do i get the fan count from that ?

Comment: graph api explorer? that´s just a tool for testing. make sure you know how to generate different tokens.

Comment: $response = $request->execute(); returns a fatal error Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute()

Comment: i googled for that error and this was one of the results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269170/facebookrequestexecute-not-included-in-facebook-sdk